# 2-D Array Method Construction

Tags: java

I am having some difficulty filling a 2-D array. Beforehand, I constructed a 2-D array with dimensions based upon user input. Basically I need to check if this statement is valid (still within the array dimensions). Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
(square[0 - i][dimension/2 + i]) // is valid / still in array dimensions
```

Thanks

Comment: It's a valid Java statement syntax-wise, but there's no way for us to tell you if it's *logically* correct, not based on the limited information that you've presented. You'll need to ask a better question.

Comment: By the way, if you need to resize your arrays, you are better off with ArrayList because they are resized automatically.  You can have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to check whether the dimensions the user entered aren't too small for you to do your thing, you'll want to use square.length and square[0].length (for the subarray).
Example:

```
int array[5][6] = new int;

System.out.println(array.length);
System.out.println(array[0].length);
```

This would return:

```
5
6
```

So you can just use .length to check whether the values are in the range you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is enclose the "suspect" statement(s) in a try-catch block, with the catch block catching an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and taking the appropiate measures for it (printing an error on the screen, for example).

Like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int i, j;

i = in.nextInt ();
j = in.nextInt ();

in.close ();

try
{
    System.out.println (the_array[i][j]); //anything else can go here (maybe add that array element to another array ?)
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    System.err.println ("invalid input"); //anything else can go here (maybe ask for another input ?)
}
```